# Value not polymorphic enough

Tags: ocaml

Here's a minimal example out of my code demonstrating the problem:

```
module Substring = struct
  type t = {
    base: string;
    pos: int;
    len: int
  }
end

module Parser = struct
  type 'a t = Substring.t -> ('a * Substring.t) option
  let return x s = Some (x, s)
end

type (_, _) t =
  | TryParse : unit Parser.t -> ('a, 'a) t
  | Parse    : 'b Parser.t -> ('a, 'b -> 'a) t
  | Concat   : ('b, 'c) t * ('a, 'b) t -> ('a, 'c) t

let p = Parse (Parser.return "xxx")
```

My problem is that I want `val p : ('a, string -> 'a) t` to be polymorphic and yet OCaml makes `'a` weak: `val p : ('_a, string -> '_a)`. I'm pretty sure I'm being bitten by the value restriction here and I'm not quite sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the value restriction. You need to eta-expand the problematic definition, like this:

```
let p = Parse (fun x -> Parser.return "xxx" x)
```

Annoying, isn't it?

If you want a binding to be polymorphic then you usually have to ensure that it is a "syntactic value". An expression containing a partial application doesn't qualify (because in general partial applications may have an effect), but a `(fun ...)` is fine.